# Toast doesn't recognize context

Tags: android, toast

I'm new to Android development and Java and I'm having troubles with Toast:

I have a MainActivity with several buttons. Each one of this starts another Activity with typical `setOnclickListener` method like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), secondaryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Then, inside this `secondaryActivity.class` I have another button that make some stuff. Inside this Activity I wanna display a Toast on button's click but it doesn't work:

```
secondaryActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

As Toast's context I've tried: `getApplicationContext()`, `getBasecontext()`, `view.getContext()`, `mySecondaryActivityClass.this`... No one of this display the Toast, I don't know where's the mistake. Supposedly, `view.getContext()` might work but it doesn't display anything...

MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity and mySecondaryActivity extends Activity.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the `Toast`? Perhaps the problem is with the button not calling your `onClick()` method when the button is clicked. Have you tried using Logcat or the debugger to confirm that your `onClick()` method is being called?

Comment: I didn't explained for simplify the problem but the button fires another function that works fine. Because of this I think the problem is related to the Toast

Answer (score 0):

You can use `secondaryActivity.this` like:

```
Toast.makeText(secondaryActivity.this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It works only on **secondaryActivity** class

Comment: Hi, I've tried and works on MainActivity but then, I can't display a Toast inside an activity distinct MainActivity? There is a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, only on activities, you mentionded "mySecondaryActivity" -->
Toast.makeText(mySecondaryActivity.this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Use className.this and dont use context. ClassName should be an Activity or extends from Activity

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```